# Install helm 2.13.0 on Minikube server (1.6.2) could not find tiller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Hey I'm installing fresh minikube and try to init helm on it no in 3.x.x but 2.13.0 version.

```
$ minikube start
  minikube v1.6.2 on Darwin 10.14.6
✨  Automatically selected the 'hyperkit' driver (alternates: [virtualbox])
  Creating hyperkit VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.17.0 on Docker '19.03.5' ...
  Pulling images ...
  Launching Kubernetes ...
⌛  Waiting for cluster to come online ...
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"

$ kubectl -n kube-system create serviceaccount tiller
serviceaccount/tiller created

$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount kube-system:tiller
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/tiller created

$ helm init --service-account tiller
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /Users/<user>/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource

$ helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -

deployment.apps/tiller-deploy created
service/tiller-deploy created

$ helm init --service-account tiller
 59 ### ALIASES
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /Users/<user>/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource

$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find tiller
```

---

I try to do same on some random other ns, and with no result:

```
$ kubectl create ns deployment-stuff
namespace/deployment-stuff created

$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
        --user=$(gcloud config get-value account)

clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cluster-admin-binding created

$ kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace deployment-stuff
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
    --serviceaccount=deployment-stuff:tiller

serviceaccount/tiller created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/tiller-admin-binding created

$ helm init --service-account=tiller --tiller-namespace=deployment-stuff

Creating /Users/<user>/.helm
Creating /Users/<user>/.helm/repository
Creating /Users/<user>/.helm/repository/cache
Creating /Users/<user>/.helm/repository/local
Creating /Users/<user>/.helm/plugins
Creating /Users/<user>/.helm/starters
Creating /Users/<user>/.helm/cache/archive
Creating /Users/<user>/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /Users/<user>/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource

$ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Skip local chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈

$ helm list
Error: could not find tiller

$ helm list --tiller-namespace=kube-system
Error: could not find tiller

$ helm list --tiller-namespace=deployment-stuff
Error: could not find tiller
```

Same error everywhere **Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource** any ideas how to approach it ?

I installed helm with those commands and works fine with my gcp clusters, helm list returns full list of helms.

```
wget -c https://get.helm.sh/helm-v2.13.0-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
tar -zxvf helm-v2.13.0-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
mv darwin-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm
```

tbh I have no idea what's going on, sometimes it works fine on minikube sometimes I get these errors.

Comment: why not helm 3?

Comment: ye when I install `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/Helm/master/scripts/get > get_Helm.sh && chmod 700 get_Helm.sh && ./get_Helm.sh` it works fine, but dunno older version have some issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be fixed by deleting the tiller `deployment` and `service` and rerunning the `helm init --override` command after first `helm init`.

So after running commands You listed:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system create serviceaccount tiller
serviceaccount/tiller created

$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount kube-system:tiller
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/tiller created

$ helm init --service-account tiller
```

And then finding out that tiller could not be found.

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find tiller
```

Run the following commands:

1.

```
$ kubectl delete service tiller-deploy -n kube-system
```

2.

```
$ kubectl delete deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system
```

3.

```
helm init --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -
```

---

After that You can verify if it worked with:

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find a ready tiller pod
```

This one needs little more time, give it few seconds.

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Tell me if it worked.

Comment: yea it works but it can be shortened just merge the two `helm init`'s into one and no need to delete

Comment: `minikube start`

Comment: `kubectl -n kube-system create serviceaccount tiller`

Comment: `kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount kube-system:tiller`

Comment: `helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -`

Comment: also rememeber that your global var `export TILLER_NAMESPACE=kube-system` is not set to any other - that took few hair from my head

Comment: hey I'm installing tiller on another cluster and this time I just get 'timeout' - helm is installed helm version is on bouth clusters, but when I run `helm list` there is new line and no response - ever met issue like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Check logs of error tiller pod by:

```
kc -n kube-system describe pod tiller-deploy-*
```

You'll see following error:

```
Failed to pull image "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.15.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Head "https://gcr.io/v2/kubernetes-helm/tiller/manifests/v2.15.1": unknown: Project 'project:kubernetes-helm' not found or deleted.
```

The reason is they changed the image location, so the old version of helm couldn't pull it.
Pull the image manually by:

```
docker pull ghcr.io/helm/tiller:v2.15.1
```

Tag the pulled image to the version that helm needed at the first place

```
docker tag ghcr.io/helm/tiller:v2.15.1 gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.15.1
```

Re-init tiller (helm server):

```
helm init
```

and you'll see the tiller deploy is running.